# Vue component not showing (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-passport

I'm trying to get Passport setup on Laravel 5.3, but the Vue components don't seem to be showing up in the blade.

Here is the code for my blade:

```
@extends('connect.frame')

@section('title')
    API Settings - KHConnect
@endsection

@section('header')
    <!-- Page Header -->
    <div class="content page-header" style="margin-bottom: 2em;">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 style="padding-top: 0.5em;font-size: 4em;">KHConnect</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection

@section('body')
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

    <div class="row">
        <passport-clients></passport-clients>
        <passport-authorized-clients></passport-authorized-clients>
        <passport-personal-access-tokens></passport-personal-access-tokens>
    </div>
@endsection
```

And here is the code in my app.js:

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * include Vue and Vue Resource. This gives a great starting point for
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

Vue.component(
    'passport-clients',
    require('./components/passport/Clients.vue')
);

Vue.component(
    'passport-authorized-clients',
    require('./components/passport/AuthorizedClients.vue')
);

Vue.component(
    'passport-personal-access-tokens',
    require('./components/passport/PersonalAccessTokens.vue')
);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

I have ran `gulp` and installed Laravel Elixir, and am loading `<script src="{{asset('js/vue.min.js')}}"></script>` and `<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>` in my blade.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are the component templates loaded properly?

Comment: I've just followed the documentation directly from official Laravel docs @keksnicoh. They are all leading to files that exist.

Comment: Can you find them in the compiled app.js? Or within the HTML of the page? What does Chromes developer console say about that?

Comment: @keksnicoh Getting this on dev console: `vue.js?3de6:525 [Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app`

Comment: oh well, do you have an element #app defined? If not sure, try to use `<div class="row" id="app">` and see what happens

Comment: Got it working with `id="app"` in the div. That must've been what it was. Thanks for the help @keksnicoh!

Comment: cool! a vue vm always needs a root element which is identified with "app" in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A vue-js vm requires a root element to work on](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Declarative-Rendering). In the question the root element id is "app":

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

But it was missing in the HTML of the page. Adding a `<div id="app">...</div>` container solved the problem as seen in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to run in cli following commands:

```
npm install
npm run production
```